eksctl and AsgInstance launch failures due to account quota limit
I was trying to launch an eks cluster using eksctl tool. The cluster is launched but the nodegroup fails to launch. The following error is displayed in the cloudformation of the nodegroup.
Error displayed in cloudformation:
Resource handler returned message: "[Issue(Code=AsgInstanceLaunchFailures, Message=You've reached your quota for maximum Fleet Requests for this account. Launching EC2 instance failed., ResourceIds=[eks-ng-e749b72b-9cc7b85c-0e51-f4a0-d7ed-931b56e7bf34])] (Service: null, Status Code: 0, Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 0bfee577-3195-082b-0033-514b8b1160d3, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
The same eks setup worked a month ago but it is throwing this error since last week. I have checked the account quotas for any limits imposed but could not find any.
Attaching the quota screenshots below
EKS service quota

EC2 autoscaling quota

Should I request for quota increase for a specific service or the issue is something else?
